# How to call php file from url by using method/function?

Tags: php

Normally we execute php file by calling file_name.php from url, Instead of calling file_name from url can i call method/function from url to execute php file? If yes,Explain me with example.

Comment: Try Slim php or any other MVC framework, they generally map a method in controller class to a url.

Comment: take a look at [Zend Framework's Routing & Controllers](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html), that is absolutely the best resource

Comment: Try some framework like codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and for this you need to use **reflection** to search method.
Also you can execute method directly:

```
$class::$method($params);
MyClass::$method();
$this->$method();
// etc...
```

But I strongly recommending to use MVC framework too.